# MXNET Gluon Error when calling two consecutive backward - Check failed: type_ != nullptr

Tags: mxnet, gluon

I need to call backward function for two different models, separately.

```
# Loss_1
#---------------------- 
  Losses_1 = []
with autograd.record():          
   for batch_per_gpu in batch es:        
       pred = model_1(batch_per_gpu)         
       loss = loss_func(pred, truth)         
       losses_1.append(loss)
   mx.autograd.backward(losses_1)
  model_1_trainer.allreduce_grads()
model_1_trainer.update()
  
#Loss_2
#---------------------- 
Losses_2 = []
with autograd.record():          
   for batch_per_gpu in batches:         
       pred = model_2(batch_per_gpu)         
       loss = loss_func(pred, truth) 
       losses_2.append(loss)
   mx.autograd.backward(losses_2) 
model_2_trainer.allreduce_grads()
 model_2_trainer.update()
```

I get this error on the second call of the backward function:

```
Check failed: type_ != nullptr: The any container is empty requested=N5mxnet10Imperative6AGInfoE
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

My MXNET version is 1.6.0